# Efficient way to find conferences in related disciplines?

Tags: conference, multidisciplinary

I have been working on my research field (astrophysics) for very long and would like to explore some adjacent disciplines such as non-linear dynamics, machine learning, ...

My university is not that big, which means it is difficult to talk to local scientists, and a possible way to learn is through attending some related conferences.

In my field, there is one website where one can find all the conferences, which I find convenient. Is it the same for other disciplines, and has anybody compiled a comprehensive list?

Comment: search, ask colleagues, periodically visit conferences websites, etc.

Comment: Check https://www.conference-service.com/conferences/gravitation-and-cosmology.html

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it is allowed to post links so I will keep my answer more general. I would start by finding conferences...like "conference for machine learning" or something similiar. Try to find good conferences that way, look how often they took place, how many people attend etc. After that you can look at interesting individual papers, look what they have done...if it interests you, check their sources and find more conferences, repeat.

The best way for me works by looking at the proceedings of good conferences, especially the videos. Most of the time they explain it so that almost anyone can understand it, which is often not the case while reading paper only(rather complex papers you need to read more than once to understand what they are doing).

Additionally you can look at journals. For example "Journal for machine learning" or "journal non-linear aerodynamics"...journals will have have different names but google is good enough to switch some words for you. Check the impact factor and compare them. Pick the one you like the most and read all the titles...spiral your way down to papers that you actually find interesting.

There are several websites that let you filter conferences or journals by topics and also rank them via some score i.e. impact factor.

At least for machine learning I can tell you the most relevant publishers are IEEE, ACM, Springer...they all have their own websites where you can apply very good filters to find what you are looking for